# How to make iOS 7 toolbar black?

Tags: ios

How can I make an iOS 7 toolbar black? It is currently the default white when I upgraded my app. I want to keep it black. I don't see a way to do this in Interface Builder. Can someone suggest a solution?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the "UINavigationBar" to be Black...

In your AppDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, add:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

This will give you a black `UINavigationBar` in your app, while having the title text still be white.

Comment: Edited my answer to show which method it should go in.